# Rollback during major upgrade from a 32-bit installer to 64-bit installer is not restoring 32 bit installer files

Tags: x86, windows-installer, installshield, rollback, major-upgrade

**Major upgrade** happens from a 32-bit installer to 64-bit installer . If rollback happens during upgrade , files from 32 bit installer "C:\Program Files(x86)" is not restored .
RemoveExistingProduct standard action is scheduled after installInitialize standard action in 64bit installer.Still the 32-bit application is not restored back . Any suggestions?